# Conditional OR has no effect in Linq-to-entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I stumbled across a null ref exception today in one of my Linq-To-Entitites queries and wondered how that could be possible. It seems an conditional OR used as an OR-gate has no effect in Linq-To-Entities. A simplified example of my query is this:

```
from a in db.Articles
where a.Author == "John Doe"
&& (tag == null || a.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName == tag.TagName))
select a;
```

Now when tag is NULL, the right side of the where query still gets executed and a NULL reference exception occurs on tag.TagName. Maybe this is because Linq-To-Entities always translates the complete statement into SQL?

Anyhow ... how to get around this issue?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = db.Articles.Where(x => x.Author == "John Doe");
query = tag == null
    ? query
    : query.Where(x => x.TagName == tag.TagName);
```

or:

```
var query = from a in db.Articles
            where a.Author == "John Doe"
            select a;

    query = tag == null
        ? query
        : from a in query
            where a.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName == tag.TagName)
            select a;
```

Personally, I find the first one cleaner

Comment: Thanks very much, Matt! I'm curious now what the generated SQL will look like ... will try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about sql. Linq converts your code as a whole into sql query passing 'outside' objects as parameters and evaluating them. That's why it fails on evaluation of your `null` object.

It's a good practice to construct a linq query bit by bit based on conditions to reduce number of unnecessary code in resulted query, so it's better to split your query:

```
var query = db.Articles.Where(x => x.Author == "John Doe");
if( tag != null)
  query = query.Where(x => x.TagName == tag.TagName);
```

Because your query will be evaluated and executed on selection you are welcome to add more conditions without worrying about multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks Dima, also for confirming the behavior that Linq-To-Entities transforms the whole query directly into SQL and does not apply any C# logic.